# private public key is different

Tags: key, private, public, keystore

I was wondering why private key is different when I use this code:

```
java.security.KeyStore keyStoreFile = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStoreFile.load(new FileInputStream("keyStore.pfx"),"password".toCharArray());
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStoreFile.getKey("alias","password".toCharArray());
String temp = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(privateKey.getEncoded()));
System.out.println(temp);
```

and when I use export private key with keytool-iui.jnlp using the same keystore?

I think this is the code wrong as it produce private key in single line.

Can anyone suggest me what to do as I need to get public key and to pass it to other programmers. But public key gets in single line as well and it's incorrect.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

To get public key from private key, you should first export private key into certificate and then from the certificate you have to import (get) public key.

After loading the keystore you can write as follows -

Certificate crt = keyStoreFile.getCertificate("aliasOfPrivateKey");
PublicKey publicKey = crt.getPublicKey();

Then get the encoded string from publicKey.

To read more about generating private - public key pair please refer following - 
http://technologytriumph.blogspot.in/2012/10/steps-to-generate-public-priavet-key.html